# Why a Syntax Error in MySQL CREATE VIEW?

Tags: mysql, view

I have been trying to create a view within MySQL WorkBench. Whilst the SELECT statement I want to use runs without any issue when I add it in to the VIEW I am told I have Syntax Errors but cannot understand why. My script is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW 
ClientMedical (LastName FirstName Highest) AS
SELECT Client.LastName, Client.FirstName, 
Qualifications.Highest FROM Client INNER JOIN Qualifications
ON Qualifications.idClient = Client.idClient  
ORDER BY Client.LastName DESC
```

Comment: Your missing a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

You're missing commas in your column list:

```
CREATE VIEW 
ClientMedical (LastName, FirstName, Highest) AS -- Note the commas
SELECT     Client.LastName, Client.FirstName, Qualifications.Highest 
FROM       Client 
INNER JOIN Qualifications ON Qualifications.idClient = Client.idClient  
ORDER BY   Client.LastName DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
CREATE VIEW 
ClientMedical (LastName FirstName Highest) AS
SELECT Client.LastName, Client.FirstName, 
Qualifications.Highest FROM Client INNER JOIN Qualifications
ON Qualifications.idClient = Client.idClient  
ORDER BY Client.LastName DESC
```

Try:

```
CREATE VIEW ClientMedical AS
SELECT Client.LastName, Client.FirstName, 
Qualifications.Highest FROM Client INNER JOIN Qualifications
ON Qualifications.idClient = Client.idClient  
ORDER BY Client.LastName DESC;
```

Comment: Even with these changes (I had tried with commas previously) it comes back "The object's DDL statement contains syntax errors."

Comment: Still the same I am afraid! I'm totally bemused!

Comment: Hmm ok, thats odd, I am following MySQL convention (per their website)..Can you try without the semicolon at the end?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in coming back - I had to leave the office to pick someone up. Anyway removing the semi-colon made no difference. I have also tried removing the ORDER BY clause by again it made no difference. The SELECT statement works fine on MySQL Workbench and also from the command line. The CREATE VIEW also reports syntax errors at the command line level - apparently near the SELECT!

Comment: Ok try this: CREATE VIEW ClientMedical AS select * from Client;

Comment: Works fine as does: 
CREATE VIEW CliMeds AS SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Client
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName;
so seems very much an issue in the JOIN!
In both cases I can then SELECT from the view...

Comment: Hmmm, can you do `\d Qualifications` and add the results to your question?

Comment: Not 100% on what you are asking me to do @ryekayo. I can CREATE a VIEW with all fields or a subset of Qualifications. I have also confirmed the fields I am joining on are of the same type(INT)...

Answer (score 0):

After being on another project for the past week I reversed the 
'ON Qualifications.idClient = Client.idClient' 
to 'ON Client.idClient =  Qualifications.idClient' 
and it worked! But why?